# Flex Image Editor issue

Tags: php, actionscript-3, imagemagick, image-manipulation, image-editing

We have developed flex image editor for editing business cards and templates. Users can add text, select font and size for the texts in that templates and save their output.

Since flex is a client-side program, it was time consuming to save that output directly from flex to our server. For this we used PHP script to save that output by receiving x,y coordinates of texts that are added by the flex.

We also needed to save those outputs as 300 dpi for printing. We were able to output the image in 300 dpi but we still have problems with alignments of texts seen in the editor and in the final output. I can say it is 90% correct.

Can someone guide me to make this 100% accurate?

Answers for the comment

We have the same template image used by flex to add text. We are adding texts to this image using ImageMagick after receiving the coordinates, font and size from the flex editor.

Regarding the font size there is one more challenge as Flex stores size as pixels and we have to convert that to points for PHP. We are  using below calculation to convert this.

points = pixels * 72 / 96

Comment: Could you add some code? Are you drawing into a BitmapData object? What's your technique so far?  We need a little more to go on...

Comment: We have the same template image used by flex to add text. We are adding texts to this image using ImageMagick after receiving the coordinates, font and size from the flex editor.

Regarding the font size there is one more challenge as Flex stores size as pixels and we have to convert that to points for PHP. We are  using below calculation to convert this.

points = pixels * 72 / 96

Comment: I see. Is it possible to have an AIR app on your server that could do the rasterization for you instead of ImageMagick? That way you could send the objects AMF serialized (small and fast) to the server, and AIR would be able to take that data and rasterize it using the same libraries that the client, so they should be identical. That's an idea at least...

Comment: Thank your for the suggestion.. But its not possible to install Adobe Air now... Do you have any other solutions? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Sounds like you'll really benefit from using vector graphics, rather than bitmaps - if you're working at 300dpi in the client, you'll be transferring a lot of data over the wire, and it may be too slow for your users. I'm doing something similar, but it's all SVG elements - the most data I need to send is a preview PNG from the server to the user, low res.

Comment: That's where I'd take it next too - as halfer said, figure out a way to go vector.  From what I can tell, the biggest limitation you'll hit is that ImageMagick may render fonts differently than Flex. Maybe halfer has a solution for that...